# Event gets called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling JQuery global function on button click

```
$.fn.editFaculty = function() {
    
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    $('#editFacultyName').val(name);
    console.log(id); //this works fine
  

    $('#update_btn').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('btn ' + id) //this keeps on adding and sends multiple requests...
    })
};
```

on button click

```
onclick="$(this).editFaculty();"
```

On button click this function gets called along with a popup and shows value in popup, then when I click update_button button then I am doing updating value (through ajax but not included in question).

Issue is when I click a button with ***id=1*** (id is not id attribute of html it means the button which corosponds to item which has id 1),

first ***console.log(id);*** shows ***1*** and second ***console.log('btn' + id)*** shows btn 1. When I again click on other button with id ***2***

first ***console.log(id);*** shows ***2*** and second ***console.log('btn' + id)*** shows ***btn 1 btn 2***.

***$('#update_btn').click(function (e){*** gets called twice and then keeps on going to 3, 4, 5, ... until I refresh page.

Comment: When you click, `editFaculty` is called, which attaches an event listener. If you click again, `editFaculty` is called, which attaches an event listener. You now have two event listeners. If you click again, `editFaculty` is called, which attaches an event listener. You now have three event listeners...

Comment: How to detach it manually so that next time it starts from fresh.
automatically or I have cancel button too can be used for this.
popup do not dismiss by clicking outside..

Comment: Is there a single update_btn?  If so, which `id` do you want it to update when you click it?     Probably easiest solution is to use `$("#update_btn").off("click").click(...`  then there will only be one event handler and it will be the for the last edit.

Comment: single #update_btn. and the latest one I want like in above example clicking second time on button with id 2 I want only btn 2    not btn 1

Comment: @freedomn-m it works. Can you write it in answer so that I accept it...

Comment: could it be that you need to call `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I ask you (not a question but an imperative) to say to yourself: "How is the event listener function added to the element?"

The response is, via the `click` method in function body.

The response is, via the `onclick` property.

So you need to determine how you are going to attach the listener.

#### Variants of solution

#### Variant 1

get the `$('#update_btn').click(` up to until the `})` outside the body of `editFaculty` function and get rid of onclick in html!

#### Variant 2

get rid of `click` method there and use just the onclick.